# C++ matrix multiplication rows and cols

Tags: c++, matrix, multiplication

Hello guys i'm trying to implement large matrix multiplication with c++ here is the code :

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "sauvegarder.h"
#include "restaurer.h"
using namespace std;

const int ligne = 2048;
const int colonne = 2048;
int main()
{
    static float host_matrice_1[ligne][colonne];
    static float host_matrice_2[ligne][colonne];
    static float host_matrice_3[ligne][colonne];
    clock_t sequentiel;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    //clock_t parallele;

    //création des matrices avec des valeurs aléatoire

    for (int i = 0; i < ligne; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colonne; j++)
        {
            host_matrice_1[i][j] = rand() * 1000;
            host_matrice_2[i][j] = rand() * 1000;
        }
    }

    sauvegarder(host_matrice_1, "matrice_1.txt");
    sauvegarder(host_matrice_2, "matrice_2.txt");

    //debut de calcul de temps + multiplication
    sequentiel = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < ligne; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colonne; j++)
        {
            host_matrice_3[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < ligne; k++)
            {
                host_matrice_3[i][j] = host_matrice_3[i][j] + host_matrice_1[i][k] * host_matrice_2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    sequentiel = clock() - sequentiel;

    cout << "Temps Cpu: " << ((float)sequentiel) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
sauvegarde.h

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int rows = 2048;
const int cols = 2048;
void sauvegarder(static float Mat[rows][cols], string filename);
```

sauvegarde.cpp

```
#include "sauvegarder.h"

void sauvegarder(static float Mat[rows][cols], string filename)
{
    ofstream output_file(filename);

    for (int ligne = 0; ligne != rows; ligne++)
    {
        if (ligne != 0)
        {
            output_file << '\n';
        }
        for (int col = 0; col != cols; col++)
        {
            if (col != 0)
            {
                output_file << '\t';
            }
            output_file << Mat[ligne][col];
        }
    }
}
```

restaurer.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int ro = 2048;
const int co = 2048;
void restorer(static float mat[ro][co], string filename);
```

restaurer.cpp

```
#include "restaurer.h"
void restorer(static float mat[ro][co], string filename)
{
    float x;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    string lineA;
    ifstream fileIN(filename);

    //static float tmp;
    while (getline(fileIN, lineA))
    {
        //Pour les chaines de caracteres et pas caractere.
        istringstream streamA(lineA);
        col = 0;
        while (streamA >> x)
        {
            mat[row][col] = x;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i want to change number of rows and cols i need to change it in every header and even in main.cpp , how can i make it changeable from one header .

Comment: Why not have your program be able to adjust the number of rows and columns at runtime?  You want to have an umpteen different programs, and the only difference is the number of rows and columns?

Comment: In alternative you could use a little templated wrapper for your arrays. `template <typename T, int N> struct Mat { 
 Mat() {
  data = new T[N];
  size = N;
 };
 int size;
 T* data;
};` So this is the 1D case, but this approach allows you to set your dimension and retrieve it via size field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a bad design for a c++ program. You should be using objects or pointers (with dynamic memory allocation) instead of fixed arrays, allowing any size at runtime (except negatives!).

Anyways, responding to your question, you can create a header file with globals, include that header on every required file, and use those constants:

```
// globals.h
// Use preprocessor directives to define the constants once (you can also youse `#pragma once`)
#ifndef __GLOBALS_H_
#define __GLOBALS_H_

const int MATRIX_COLS = 2048;
const int MATRIX_ROWS = 2048;

#endif /* __GLOBALS_H_ */
```

And use it in your code like this:

```
#include "restaurer.h"
#include "globals.h"

void restorer(static float mat[MATRIX_ROWS][MATRIX_COLS], string filename) {
  // ...
}
```

Don't forget to replace and remove all of yours `co` and `ro` constants.